# Get Stream Type from Rtp Packets or by Other Methods

Tags: directshow, h.264, rtp, mpeg-4

I have simple Rtsp Source Filter which connects Rtsp Server and get Rtp packets. The problem is that i have to set media subtype in my Rtsp Source Filter Pin...[ Now i give substype hard-coded]

```
pMediaType->SetSubtype(&MyHardCodedSubTypeGUID);
```

What i want is create my pin dynamically with subtype according to coming stream. I get h264 and mpeg-4 streams from server.Their rtp packet payload  format is dynamic: 96...Does not help me to identify if stream is mpeg4 or h264...

FFmpeg can able to get stream type[h264,mpeg4] from codec info...But how can i do myself?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTP payload is not only dynamic (96, 97 etc), it is also provided with payload type attributes you need to obtain format from and convert into DirectShow media type (see "**H264***" below):

```
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96 
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000 
a=control:trackID=1
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
```